# Determining ratios to reach average of a quantity of 3 values

Tags: algorithm, math

I've got constants A, B, C, and N, and I'd like to figure out how to "mix" quantities of A, B, and C to create an average of N.

In a formula, it looks like this:

```
(xA + yB + zC)/(x+y+z) = N
```

How do I figure out values for x,y,z?

Edit: I'm not looking for a finite solution, I'm looking for a best-fit algorithm that will return the lowest value of the sum of x, y, and z.

Comment: not possible. you've got 3 unknowns, and one single equation. unless you pick out some values for x and y (say), then you could solve for z.

Comment: I'm looking for a best-fit, not a finite solution.  It'd be acceptable to "guess" for some values of x,y, and z.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question of programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There's an **infinite** number of triplets {x,y,z} in the real numbers that would solve your problem. Even if you require that {x,y,z} be positive integers there may be more than one solution. To see that, think of your problem as trying to solve this problem: find p1, p2, and p3 such that

```
A p1 + B p2 + C p3 = N
```

where

```
p1 = x/(x+y+z)
p2 = y/(x+y+z)
p3 = z/(x+y+z)
```

You have 2 equations, A p1 + B p2 + C p3 = N and p1 + p2 + p3 = 1, with 3 unknowns {p1, p2, p3}, so there are an infinite number of solutions.

As per the discussion in the comments below, there's a way to find **a** solution, even though there is no unique solution. It goes like this, in pseudo-code:

```
gotp3 = false
while !gotp3 {
    gotp2 = false
    while !gotp2 {
        p1 = random number in the range [0,1]
        p2 = ( (N-C) - (A-C)*p1 ) / (B-C)
        gotp2 = (p2 >= 0 && p2 <= 1)
    }
    p3 = 1 - p1 - p2
    gotp3 = (p3 >= 0 && p3 <= 1)
}
s = random number in any interval you want // s = x+y+z
x = p1 * s
y = p2 * s
z = p3 * s
```

Note that there's a problem when B=C but I'll let you figure a way out then, based on what I've already written.

One last thing. Note that if N > (A + B + C) then there is NO solution because the average of a set of numbers must always be less than the sum of those numbers. You might want to test for that as well, at the top.

**Note added after @EdwardDoolittle's answer found below**

Although I'm technically correct that there are an infinite number of solutions, @EdwardDoolittle is quite right in that there is a well-defined algorithm to obtain a unique solution **when we require that the sum of the squares of the pi values be as small as possible**. In fact, that statement is true even when we have an arbitrary number of values to average. However, there's no need to invoke a matrix library as the solution of the general problem is quite simple. In the interest of completion, I'm going to present the solution to the general problem, rather than just for 3 values.

**General problem**

Given a real number N and m real values ai, where 1 <= i <= m, find a set of m values pi such that sum(pi) = 1 and sum(pi*ai) = N while having the smallest possible value of sum(pi^2).

**The solution** is the following:

```
pi = ( sum(aj^2) - (N + ai) * sum(aj) + m * N * ai ) / D
```

where

```
D = m * sum(aj^2) - ( sum(aj) )^2

sum(aj) = a1 + a2 + ... + am

sum(aj^2) = a1^2 + a2^2 + ... + am^2
```

**The proof** (sketched, not in all its detail)

Define a quantity

```
S = sum(pi^2) - U * ( sum(pi) - 1 ) - V * ( sum(pi*ai) - N )
```

where U and V (the so-called Lagrange multipliers) are constants to be determined. Note that S reduces to sum(pi^2) if/when the pi values satisfy the conditions of the problem, that is, that they sum to 1 and that they are the weights in the averaging of the ai values that result in N. However, before we impose those conditions, S is some complicated function of the pi values.

Now suppose we want to minimise the value of S over all possible choices of the pi values. A necessary condition for S to attain an extremum (minimum or maximum) is that its first-order partial derivatives with respect to the pi values all vanish:

```
dS/dpi = 2 * pi - U - V * ai = 0
```

This set of m equations gives us the pi values that make S an extremum:

```
2 * pi = U + V * ai
```

Now, to find U and V, sum the above equation over i and sum the same equation multiplied by ai, over i. That gives us 2 equations

```
2 * sum(pi)    = U * m       + V * sum(ai)
2 * sum(pi*ai) = U * sum(ai) + V * sum(ai^2)
```

but now we impose the conditions of the problem and set sum(pi) = 1 and sum(pi*ai) = N and obtain

```
    2 = U * m       + V * sum(ai)
2 * N = U * sum(ai) + V * sum(ai^2)
```

Next we solve for U and V then plug those back into the equation for the pi values and the result is what I quoted earlier. Lastly, by looking at the second-order partial derivatives we can see that the extremum is actually a minimum if the pi values are positive:

```
d^2S/dpi^2 = pi

minimum  <=>  d^2S/dpi^2 > 0  <=>  p1 > 0
```

**BOTTOM LINE**

I'd say ignore my initial proposal of randomly selecting values and, instead, go for the solution I just described. It's unique and very simple to compute.

Comment: I'm not looking for a finite solution, I'm looking for a best-fit algorithm to come up with the solution containing the lowest answer of x+y+z.

Comment: Even then, there are an infinite number of solutions. Here's one way to see that: suppose that you set y = x. Then you can solve for z as follows: z = (A+B-2N) x / (N-C). Then the sum x + y + z = 2x + z = (A + B - 2C) x / (N - C). To minimise the sum, you want to minimise x. The solution x = 0 is not valid because then x = y = z = 0 and your (x+y+z) denominator equals 0. So, you can choose x as small as you like (but not zero), hence an infinite number of solutions still.

Comment: Would it help to limit x, y, and z to integers?

Comment: To provide an example, A=1, B=10, C=100, and N=10, a solution would be x=10, y=5, z=1.  While it might not be the only solution, it is *a* solution, which is acceptable.

Comment: If you limit them to integers, there may still exist many solutions, and there may not exist a solution at all, as well. Now, I think I found a way to give you an answer that will satisfy you. Like I said, the problem you posed is equivalent to A p1 + B p2 + C p3 = N with p1 + p2 + p3 = 1, where the ps are defined above. Now, p3 must equal 1 - p1 - p2, so eliminate that and you get (A-C) p1 + (B-C) p2 = (N-C). Now solve for p2 and you get p2 = [ (N-C) - (A-C) p1 ] / (B-C). Again, infinite number of solutions. However, note that p1 must be in the range [0,1] (same is true of p2 and p3). So...

Comment: Choose a random value for p1 in the range [0,1], then compute p2 from above. If p2 turns out also in the range [0,1] then you have a possible solution, otherwise generate another random p1 and compute p2 again. Keep doing this until you have both p1 and p2 in the range [0,1]. Next, compute p3 = 1 - p1 - p2. If p3 is in the range [0,1], you have a solution, else go back to the start and generate a random p1, then compute p2 and p3. Keep doing that until all 3 values are in the range [0,1]. Once you have the ps, choose a value for (x+y+z) and multiply that against p1 to get x,

Comment: against p2 to get y and against p3 to get z.

Comment: I like this, if you update your answer to provide this solution I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is quite reasonable. One way to handle this sort of problem is to look for the solution `(p1,p2,p3)` of minimum length. There is a definite procedure for doing so, and it gives a definite, single outcome. Suppose our system is

```
|A B C| |p1|   |N|
|1 1 1| |p2| = |1|
        |p3|
```

where `p1, p2, p3` are the three weights of `A, B, C` in the mixture. We can name the three matrices as follows

```
    |A B C|      |p1|      |N|
M = |1 1 1|, x = |p2|, y = |1|
                 |p3|
```

Then we construct the **pseudo-inverse** of M and solve the equation as follows:

```
x = M^T (M M^T)^{-1} y
```

The vector `x` then solves the system, and is the vector of minimum length which does so. The above equation can be obtained through calculations with Lagrange multipliers, but you don't need to know about that to use it.

In your case, I did the calculations by hand without much difficulty, and obtained the solution

```
p1 = ( (3*A-S)*N - A*S+T ) / ( (A-B)^2 + (B-C)^2 + (C-A)^2 )
p2 = ( (3*B-S)*N - B*S+T ) / ( (A-B)^2 + (B-C)^2 + (C-A)^2 )
p3 = ( (3*C-S)*N - C*S+T ) / ( (A-B)^2 + (B-C)^2 + (C-A)^2 )
```

where `S=A+B+C` and `T=A^2+B^2+C^2`. You can check that it satisfies all the requirements of your problem, and you can compare with other solutions to get a sense that my solution is the minimum. See below for a Java implementation which takes A, B, C, and N on the command line and prints out the weights of the optimal mixture as percents. Note that near extremes (when `N` is close to `min(A,B,C)` or `max(A,B,C)`) the pseudo-inverse method gives a negative weight. In that case you should set the corresponding weight to 0 and calculate the other two variables using standard linear algebra techniques. If `N` is outside of the interval from `min(A,B,C)` to `max(A,B,C)` it is impossible to get a non-negative mixture so the implementation prints out an answer with a negative weight.

In general the calculations are fast and straightforward if you have a matrix library. For more information search for pseudo-inverse or pseudoinverse.

```
public class Mixture {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // calculate an optimal mixture of A, B, C to make N
    double A = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    double B = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
    double C = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
    double N = Double.parseDouble(args[3]);

    // these formulas were derived from calculations of the pseudo-inverse
    // of the matrix {{A,B,C},{1,1,1}}
    double S = A + B + C;
    double T = A*A + B*B + C*C;
    double D = (A-B)*(A-B) + (B-C)*(B-C) + (C-A)*(C-A);

    double p1 = ( (3*A-S)*N + (-A*S+T)) / D;
    double p2 = ( (3*B-S)*N + (-B*S+T)) / D;
    double p3 = ( (3*C-S)*N + (-C*S+T)) / D;

    // if pseudo-inverse calculation gives a negative weight, set weight to 0
    // and calculate exact solution
    if (p1<0) { p1 = 0; p2 = (N-C)/(B-C); p3 = (B-N)/(B-C); }
    if (p2<0) { p2 = 0; p1 = (N-C)/(A-C); p3 = (A-N)/(A-C); }
    if (p3<0) { p3 = 0; p1 = (N-B)/(A-B); p2 = (A-N)/(A-B); }

    p1 = Math.round(p1*1000)/10.0;
    p2 = Math.round(p2*1000)/10.0;
    p3 = Math.round(p3*1000)/10.0;

    System.out.println("Mixture weights: " + p1 + "%, " + p2 + "%, " + p3 + "%");
    System.out.println("Check p1*A+p2*B+p3*C = " + ((p1*A+p2*B+p3*C)/100));
    System.out.println("Check p1 + p2 + p3 = " + (p1+p2+p3) + "%");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Nice solution. Imposing p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2 to be a minimum provides the missing constraint that lets the problem admit a single solution, if one exists. Charles, I suggest you use @EdwardDoolitle's solution instead of mine. It's deterministic and much cleaner, in my opinion. If you don't understand the details of his answer, that's ok. All you really need is the part after "In your case, I did the calculations..."

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer, however I'm not sure I'm understanding its implementation.

Comment: If I put in real values for A, B, C, and N (1, 10, 100, and 10), I get the values of -63, -624, and -6236 respectively for p1, p2, and p3.  Intuitively, I know the answers for p1-p3 to be 10, 5, and 1.  Is my arithmetic bad, or is there some way to convert the values of p1-p3 as given by the above calculations into the values I know to be correct (by example, Ax + By + Cz/(x+y+z) becomes 10*1+5*10+1*100/16 which is 10, the expected N value)?

Comment: If you want to find the mixture with weights p1,p2,p3 of three numbers A, B, C adding to N (i.e., p1*A + p2*B + p3*C=N, p1+p2+p3=1) which minimizes the vector length of the mixture vector (p1,p2,p3), just copy and paste the formulas in my answer. If you want to solve more general problems, formulate them as linear systems Mx=y in matrix form, get a matrix library, and use it to calculate M^t (the transpose of M), M*M^T (the matrix product of M and M^T), (M*M^T)^{-1} (the inverse of the previous), and then the product M*(M*M^T)^{-1} y which is your answer x.

Comment: Well I did this (copy/paste, and thank you very much for that work, again), but the results I got did not match with what I was expecting.  I just wonder if I made an arithmetic error, or if I failed to describe the problem, or if I'm having a general misunderstanding of the solution, is all.

Comment: Basically, why don't I get p1=10, p2=5, p3=1 for values of A=10, B=5, C=1, N=10?

Comment: I just noticed that you are also asking to minimize the sum x + y + z in your problem. Is that important? If so, it's a different problem, a **linear programming** problem. Then you need to minimize x + y + z subject to the constraints (A-N)x + (B-N)y + (C-N)z = 0, x>=0, y>=0, z>=0. You solve that in a quite different manner, by checking the extreme (x,y,z) and substituting those values into x+y+z. My solution minimizes x^2+y^2+z^2 which is much easier.

Comment: It's actually not very important -- the primary driver for this question is related to a performance testing tool I'm writing, and I'm trying to figure out the correct mix of file sizes to send to the system under test.  I want an average of 10MB per file, but I want the range to be from 1-100, and I only have a few types of files to send (1MB, 10MB, and 100MB).  I just want to know how many 1MB, 10MB, and 100MB files to send so my average file size is 10MB.  If I end up with a solution that doesn't minimize for x+y+z, that's okay.

Comment: To be clear, I'm hunting for a general solution, not just for 1/10/100.

Comment: I understand. Then my suggestion is good. There must be an error in my arithmetic, let me check and get back.

Comment: I made a mistake when I transferred the formulas from paper. A * should have been +; I've corrected above. I used Wolfram Alpha "{{A,1},{B,1},{C,1}} . inverse [ {{A,B,C},{1,1,1}}.{{A,1},{B,1},{C,1}} ] " to check. You can also just ask Wolfram Alpha for "pseudoinverse {{A,B,C},{1,1,1}}" but it will give you the answer with stars for complex conjugates, which you can ignore because the variables are all real. Also note that the solution is a little different if p1+p2+p3 = something other than 1 ... but then you just scale up (e.g., to get p1+p2+p3 = 100, just multiply by 100).

Comment: Sigh ... ignore the last sentence in my comment above. You want p1+p2+p3 = 1 = 100%. Then the formulas give you the percentages. So for A=1, B=10, C=100, 49.5% should be A, 45.5% should be B, and 5% should be C.

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle "If you want to solve more general problems, formulate them as linear systems Mx=y in matrix form, get a matrix library, and use it to calculate M^t" - No need for a matrix library. The general solution I added to my original answer below has a closed analytical form. And, yes, it agrees with the solution you provided for the specific 3-variable case here.